# Changing domestic itinerary on a Spain Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I have a Spain Schengen visa, but my plan changed. The dates changed by 2 weeks, and when submitting my application I mentioned going to Madrid, but now I want to go to Barcelona. Will there be any problem?

Visa duration is 15 days, valid 20th August to 19 September.
I given detail like hotel reservations and ticket. 
20th August to 25 August 2018 stay in Madrid Spain now my plan is changed new dates is 5th September to 10 September stay in Barcelona visa type is C, schengen estancia.

Comment: Welcome to the site nadeem. We are a site which does not want to have duplicate questions and will only accept one version of each question. Therefor I have deleted your later copy of the question. If you want to add information or change information in this question you can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

As Barcelona and Madrid are both in Spain, changing the airport will not make much of a difference.
Only if you had to give details for each day of your stay, including hotel reservations, you may get asked about the change in your plans. And with that kind of detailed plans you best not change anything.

The change in date is more important.
Whether that is allowed depends on how the dates on your visa are given. If the dates are given as 'so many days in a longer period' and your new dates fall in that longer period, you are OK.
But if your dates are just covering your old plans you will need to apply for a new visa for the new dates.

If you can give us the details of your visa, like the valid from-to, the number of days, and any other restrictions printed or written on it, we might be able to help you better.
Please edit the information into this question and not as a new question.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply, visa duration is 15days valid 20th August to 19 September, I given detail like hotel reservations and ticket  20th August to 25 August 2018 stay in Madrid  Spain  now my plan is changed  new dates  is 5th September to 10 September stay in Barcelona visa type is C, schengen estancia,

Comment: You are alright for the dates and the country, I think you are alright for the change in city but I hope there are users here who are more specialist to help you further. I have edited the information into your question, where it helps the most people.

Comment: This looks OK for Schengen; it's only six days and in the same country.

Comment: While you should tell the truth if asked by the border guard, Barcelona and Madrid are linked by high-speed train; it would be common and unremarkable for a tourist to do both, or even enter at the other for a better airfare. I doubt there will be any problem since the visa encompasses the dates of both itineraries.